# How to reload UITableView when I add a new element to NSMutableArray in another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, key-value-observing

I have a singleton object which has ivar `NSMutableArray` which holds images global to application. And I have a `UITableViewController` class which represents image attaches to the message.I want to do next: when user select images from Camera Roll they are added to that singleton's array. And I want to reload `tableview` of my `UITableViewController` at once to display these new messages. How can I implement this? Should I use Key-Value Observing for this and if yes how can I do this? (I should notify when new object will be added to array). Or may be there are some other more correct way?

Comment: When you add object to array call [tableview reloadData]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know exactly what u need to Do.[Download this Demo](https://github.com/raviparmar/GKImagePicker) for reference.

it has delegate method

```
    - (void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image{

     // add your code here for adding image to Your mutable array and then Reload your tableView.

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about sending a `NSNotification` when you want the view to reload?

The `UITableView` can receives the notification and reload the data.

Answer (score 0):

add notification in which class has table

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(actionremovecalender:)
                                                 name:@"subMitReport"
                                               object:nil];
-(void)actionremovecalender:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   //table relaod code
}
call to another class
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"subMitReport" object:self];
```